# Proper form of addressing ecclesiastics in writing?

Tags: formal, letters, greeting, letter-writing

What is the proper form of addressing ecclesiastics (bishops, cardinals, superiors, sisters, et al.) when writing letters in Italian? How should such a letter be concluded?

Comment: See [this article](https://wikihow.it/Indirizzare-una-Lettera-a-un-Prete).

Comment: @Charo Very good reference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find on Treccani's [appellativi e epiteti [prontuario]](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/appellativi-e-epiteti-prontuario_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/) a list of  proper forms for most of ecclesiastics and their abbravistions.

For a bishop:

> (Sua) Eccellenza (S. Ecc. o Sua Ecc.): vescovo o alto prelato; nella
>   tradizione, prefetti e questori, e così via;

for a cardinal:

> (Sua) Eminenza (S.E. o S. Em.), Eminentissimo (Em.mo, E.mo):
>   cardinale, capo religioso;

As pointed out by @DaG, you could use:

> Eccellenza reverendissima, or Eminenza reverendissima

Answer (score -3):

In italian the proper form to init is: "Eccellenza,  " 
:)

Comment: see https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocollo_(cerimoniale)

Comment: ...or _Eccellenza reverendissima_, or _Eminenza reverendissima_, or..., depending on the ranks, and this is orally. Is in written form the same, @user205137? (And why the smiling emoticon?)

Comment: What are the abbreviations for these forms of address?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! What we're expecting here is a more detailed and reasoned answer.