# Thank you card Salutation to an Italian priest

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request, formal, greeting, letter-writing

I would like to express Dear Father Rossi.  But I do not want to use the word Caro.

Is this correct?

Egregio Padre Rossi,

Comment: I think *egregio* is a little too formal for addressing a priest... maybe *gentile* is slightly better, but it is also formal. For me is a difficult question!

Comment: Related question:  https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/9391/.

Comment: I think the way you should address to this priest in your letter would probably depend on the degree of familiarity or friendship you have with them. May we have some details about this?

Answer (score 2):

[According to this page](https://www.wikihow.it/Indirizzare-una-Lettera-a-un-Prete) a formal salutation could be

> Reverendo Padre Rossi

while

> Egregio Padre

is slightly less formal.

Also according to the same page, the letter should end with a phrase like

> La prego di accogliere, Reverendo Canonico (NAME AND SURNAME) l'espressione dei miei sentimenti deferenti
>
> (YOUR NAME AND SURNAME)

or

> Con rispetto e devozione in Cristo, (YOUR NAME AND SURNAME)

I would have suggested also *Stimato* but I guess it is not used and  *Egregio* would be better.